# PHP is not running through command line

Tags: php, command-line, command, mamp, mamp-pro

I want to work on a Larval project. On running any command relevant to PHP like php -v etc. It is showing me this error

```
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.20/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

Let me paste a screenshot.

[image]

I am using MAMP Pro on mac.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in the `export PATH= /...` after =

Answer (score 0):

```
Open a terminal and type php -v to see the current version of php.

Determine the path for the wanted php version of mamp (YOUR VERSION ON YOUR COMPUTER!)

example : /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/php
Type in the terminal cd ~ to change the current directory (in your home)

Then, type nano .bash_profile to open an editor in your terminal

Type alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/php', don't forget to replace the php version

Now, you must save the file so press CTRL+X, then type Y and finally type Enter

You must restart (stop && start || close && open) your terminal and type php -v again

You now use the php version of mamp when you type php in the terminal
```